# Changing JSON Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to "push" information to a json object.

**I have this json object:**

```
var lol = {
    "locations": {
        "United States": [
            {
                "Illinois": [
                    {
                        "Chicago": "http://website1.com/",
                        "Springfield": "http://website2.com/"
                    }
                ],
                "New York": [
                    {
                        "New York": "http://website3.com/",
                        "Brooklyn": "http://website4.com/"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

**I am trying to do a few things:**

1. How can I add ("push") a new city row to a specific state? (Ex. add "Queens" to New York)
2. How can I check if a state already exists in the object?
3. How can I sort cities in a state alphabetically?

Comment: That is not JSON. JSON is a string. What you have there is an object literal. Moving on...

Comment: Is this a "How do I JavaScript" question?

Comment: Objects are unordered, and your arrays are useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let's tidy up your object. You have too many brackets.

```
var lol = {
    "locations": {
        "United States": {
            "Illinois": {
                "Chicago": "http://website1.com/",
                "Springfield": "http://website2.com/"
            },
            "New York": {
                "New York": "http://website3.com/",
                "Brooklyn": "http://website4.com/"
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Now that that's done, adding a new city is simple:

```
lol.locations["United States"]["New York"]["Queens"] = "http://website5.com/";
```

Checking if a state exists:

```
if( lol.locations["United States"]["Illinois"]) {
    // it exists! Do something!
}
```

Sorting cities is a little harder. Objects are unsortable, the keys are handled by the browser. That said, you can use an array "helper":

```
var cities = Object.keys(lol.locations["United States"]["New York"]);
cities.forEach(function(city) {
    console.log(city+": "+lol.loctions["United States"]["New York"][city]);
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: also for the sorting.. you forgot the `.sort()` at the end. `Object.keys(...).sort()`